# Python Binary Search ('NoneType' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

```
import InsertionSortPackage as ISP

inp = input("Enter a list of number:").split(",")
inp = [float(j) for j in inp]
num = input("Number you want to find:")
a = ISP.insertion(inp)
n = len(inp)
num = float(num)

def binary_search():
    not_found = True
    first = 1
    last = n
    #Its gotta have something to do with the while loop
    while(not_found):
        if first < last:
            print("Your number does not exist.")

        mid = (first + last)//2
        # Maybe you can make only print the last repeat for the while loop      
        if a[mid] == num:
            print("Your number found at location " + str(mid+1))
            not_found = False
        else:
            if a[mid] < num:
                first = mid + 1        
            elif a[mid] > num:
                last = mid - 1           


binary_search()
```

Its now printing this: "Number you want to find:2
Your number does not exist.
Your number does not exist.
Your number found at location 2"

Comment: `ISP.insertion(inp)` is inline insertion. So the **result** is not a list. You have to work on `inp`, not on `a`...

Comment: Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Well since `a = ISP.insertion(inp)` and `insertion(..)` does **not** return anything, `a` will be `None` and you cannot call like `None[1]`...